# How can I prevent Windows Explorer from stealing the focus when a file transfer completes?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-transfer, window-focus

How can I prevent Windows Explorer from stealing the focus when a file transfer in Windows Explorer completes?

I use Windows 10 Pro 21H2.

Comment: Your file transfer started with Windows Explorer (apparently) and ends there, so I don't think you can do what you want. If you use a Web Browser the same thing occurs.  Just move your mouse to what want,  That is what I do here.

Comment: If you are doing an inline process (some automation) you might try a command driven file transfer that can be controlled in a batch file or script.

Comment: Is it the dialog that takes focus, or the Explorer window itself? There are alternative file transfer utilities. Have you tried any? And what research have you done so far?

Comment: @music2myear Explorer window itself, upon completion of the transfer. Yes, no problem with Teracopy but I was trying to use Explorer's native copy function.

Comment: Had this same problem today. Very frustrating. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @WackGet no :-(